# JBoss EAP 7.0.5.GA to Wildfly 24: "Subclass has to be binded after it's mother class"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

i am migrating a JBoss EAP 7.0.5.GA application in a first step to a wildfly 24.0.1. Now it seems that some Jpa/ Hibernate features changed or broke (the application still runs fine on JBoss EAP 7.0.5.GA).

On Wildfly 24 i get:

```
HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Subclass has to be binded after it's mother class: somthing.server.kiam.common.model.ParishRef
11:05:46,887 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."somthing.server.ear/somthing.server.main.jar#project": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."somthing.server.ear/somthing.server.main.jar#project": org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Subclass has to be binded after it's mother class: somthing.server.kiam.common.model.ParishRef
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Subclass has to be binded after it's mother class: somthing.server.kiam.common.model.ParishRef
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.getSuperEntity(AnnotationBinder.java:1272)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:562)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1215)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1246)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
        ... 10 more
```

The class it moans about is "ParishRef":

```
@Embeddable
public class ParishRef implements KiamDatatype {

    public interface JSONViews {
        interface ParishRefFull {
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String parishId;

    @ProjectField
    private String parishName;

  // getters seters, hashcode equals
}
```

This is used in other entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "communion")
public class Communion implements KIAMWithHistory<CommunionHistory>, KIAMDefaults,
        CreateAndModifyAware, ProjectTenantEntity {

    public interface JSONViews {
        interface CommunionFull extends
                KIAM.JSONViews.KIAMFull,
                ParishRef.JSONViews.ParishRefFull,
                BaptismParish.JSONViews.BaptismParishFull,
                PersonDetail.JSONViews.PersonDetailFull,
                Person.JSONViews.PersonFull {
        }
    }

    //fields

    @ProjectField
    private String remark;

    @ProjectField(mapping = ParishRef.class) // field with problem
    private ParishRef communion;

    @ProjectField(mapping = BaptismParish.class)
    private BaptismParish baptism;
   // otherfields, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

For sake of completeness here the annotation (only a marker)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface ProjectField {

    /**
     * Defines the mapped class
     * 
     * @return the class to map to.
     */
    Class<? extends KiamDatatype> mapping() default KiamDatatype.class;

    /**
     * Defines the type of m to n mapping.
     * 
     * @return The class to map to.
     */
    Class<? extends ProjectEnum> type() default KIAMType.class;

}
```

So what is the problem in regards of the error "Subclass has to be binded after it's mother class: de.rk.Project.server.kiam.common.model.ParishRef"?

Some classes are extending ParishRef and some use ParishRef and extending classes as their fields (using the concrete class as field type).
So how to get hibernate to "bind" in correct order of inheritance?
Or how to fix this and why this stopped working?

thx in advance